# Why kotlin gradle plugin cannot build with 1.8 target?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have the simplest gradle project configured using intellij for kotlin 1.2.10. Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.10'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

group 'com.ali'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

And I have a simple java interface:

```
public interface MyMath {
    static int myAbs(int input) {
        return Math.abs(input);
    }
}
```

When I import this interface and try to call `myAbs` method it fails with this error:

```
Error:(6, 12) Kotlin: Calls to static methods in Java interfaces are prohibited in JVM target 1.6. Recompile with '-jvm-target 1.8'
```

I have created an intellij kotlin app and it was working correctly. Is it a bug in new Kotlin gradle plugin?

Comment: Do you have JDK 8?

Comment: Yes, and this problem only happens when I build the project in intellij. gradle in terminal works fine!

Comment: What is the IDE plugin version that you use? I could not reproduce the error with the 1.2.21 plugin. If that happens with the newer Gradle & IDE plugin versions as well, you could file an issue at [kotl.in/issue](https://kotl.in/issue) and describe the exact steps that lead to the error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60246275/4694013

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It turned out that it was my kotlin compiler configuration in intellij settings. In `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Kotlin Compiler` a setting called `Target JVM version` should have been set to 1.8.

Comment: In my version it's in `Settings -> Other Settings -> Kotlin Compiler -> Target JVM Version`

Comment: But even when set to 1.8, I still get `Calls to static methods in Java interfaces are prohibited in JVM target 1.6. Recompile with '-jvm-target 1.8'`

Comment: I don't have `Other Settings` in mine!

Comment: In my case I fix it in `Project Structure -> Facets -> Kotling -> Target Platform`

Comment: Actually, I set all of the above and no more message... yet. IJ 2018.1.5  Kotlin 1.2.50.

Answer (score 200):

I think this could be helpful for those using Android Studio 3.2 on Mac.

To change the Kotlin Compiler Target JVM version you should go to Android Studio -> Preferences -> Kotlin Compiler and then change the Target JVM version choosing from the dropdown.

Anyway, I'm still getting the following error

> Calls to static methods in Java interfaces are prohibited in JVM target 1.6. Recompile with '-jvm-target 1.8'

**SOLVED**

Adding the following to my build.gradle solved the problem:

```
android {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}
```

About this and other Gradle configuration options: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

---

With Kotlin Gradle DSL:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmOptions

(kotlinOptions as KotlinJvmOptions).apply {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
}
```

Comment: For Android projects, the Kotlin compiler target JVM version needs to be changed in build.gradle, not in the Android Studio preferences. Changes in the Android Studio preferences will not affect command-line builds.

Comment: If someone gets the reason behind this error then please leave a comment tagging me.

Comment: Works for Android Studio 3.5.

Comment: Cool, it helps! And it's `app`'s gradle btw.

Comment: Is it possible to set this at the root build.gradle file? It's tedious managing this across modules in a multi-module project.

Comment: Is there a way to set 1.8 as default?

Comment: not work i s have set it

Answer (score 25):

There is a gradle property used by Kotlin plugin which can be used. When you add

```
kotlin.setJvmTargetFromAndroidCompileOptions = true
```

to your `gradle.properties` file.
When you have this configuration on your `build.config`

```
android{
  compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility = 1.8
      targetCompatibility = 1.8
  }
}
```

problem sould be solved.

Comment: The project I was working on had `sourceCompatibility ` & `targetCompatibility` configured but adding the `kotlin.setJvmTargetFromAndroidCompileOptions = true` solved the problem for me

Comment: where is i put the kotlin.setJvmTargetFromAndroidCompileOptions = true code ? more spesific pls

Comment: in gradle.properties at any level

Answer (score 24):

Please check if you have the following three stuff set in idea:

1. kotlin options in build.gradle

```
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
```

2. Check the relevant Idea preferences
   [image: Preferences]
3. Check the project Facets
   [image]

Answer (score 15):

//Just add the below code in your Build gradle(Module:app)

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yep, this helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me in Gradle with Kotlin DSL:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
val compileKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is also set in project settings, under `Project Settings > Modules > Kotlin`. This was my specific problem... literally the last thing I tried.

Answer (score 3):

Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Kotlin Compiler a setting called Target JVM version should have been set to 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure why this works, but you could try changing the setting in the Idea itself. Since Gradle from the command line works, but not when building from IntelliJ this is probably the root.

Go to File -> Project Structure. Go to the Project tab and make sure Project SDK is 8 (or newer) and set the `Project language level` to Java 8

[image]

The config in there seems to override Gradle for some reason, so changing it should work

Comment: It is 8 in my intellij!

Comment: Try invalidating the caches and restarting

Comment: Didn't work. I have a project created with older intellij (current is 2017.3.4). The old one is working. I am comparing .idea folders of two project with each other. Does it make sense?

Comment: I had the same error on a maven project. Just solved adding  <kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>1.8</kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget> to the properties section. Take a look here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17492 for more info

Comment: The "Project language level" setting controls how Java source code is highlighted in the IDE. It has no impact on Kotlin compilation whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it solved my problem. I had a problem inViewModel Factory.
//Just add the below code in your Build gradle(Module:app)

**Error** "Inheritance from an interface with '@JvmDefault' members is only allowed with -Xjvm-default option"

```
    kotlinOptions {
    freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjvm-default=compatibility']
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried all @alisabzevari options including given in comment, but It didn't work,

my mistake I added java file also in `src/<sourcset_name>kotlin/` folder, later I converted java file to kotlin file. and Voila! It works.

May be it will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

solved it by editing `build.gradle.kts`

```
val compileKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
```